# change column value to vertical in MSchart

Tags: c#, mschart

I create a chart with MSchart but for some charts I wanna to make data values of each column to be vertical. There is no much space for labels to be horizontal. I see some similar question but none of them works for me.

[image: Data Values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn the `DataPoint` labels you need to first turn off the `SmartLabelStyle`:

```
 chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Now you can set the `LabelAngle` :

```
 chart1.Series[0].LabelAngle = 90;
```